# error c2143 missing ';' before '>>' and error c2143 missing ';' before '<<' for cin and cout in c++ in visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, googletest

I am writing a program in google test and c++ in visual studio 2005. The program simply performs 4 arithmetic operations...

Initially I had written a program with hard-coded values and it worked fine. But now I want the user to give input and hence need to use `cin` and `cout` in the program. But it gives me following error when I add `cin` and `cout` statements in my code:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<<' and error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not 
support default-int for cout and
```

same for cin

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '>>' and error C4430: 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not 
support default-int
```

I have three separate files: one unit-test file, other file I have written all tests in `gtest` and third one I have linked the main file provided by google test.

Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "unittestcomplex.h"
using namespace std;

float a,b;

cout << "Enter two numbers:";
cin >> a >> b;
Arithmatic num;

TEST(complex, Addition)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(a+b,num.addition(a,b));
}
TEST(complex,subtraction)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(a-b,num.subtraction(a,b));
}
TEST(complex,multiplication)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(a*b,num.multiplication(a,b));
}
TEST(complex,division)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(a/b,num.division(a,b));
}
```

Here is the file where I have written all the functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
# include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
class Arithmatic 
{
public: 
    float addition(float a, float b);
    float subtraction(float a, float b);
    float multiplication(float a, float b);
    float division(float a, float b);
};

float Arithmatic::addition(float a, float b)
{
    float sum;
    sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}

float Arithmatic::subtraction(float a, float b)
{
    float difference;
    difference = a-b;
    return difference;
}
float Arithmatic::multiplication(float a, float b)
{
    float mult;
    mult = a*b;
    return mult;
}
float Arithmatic::division(float a, float b)
{
    float div;
    div = a/b;
    return div;
}
```

and main() is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{    
      testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
      RUN_ALL_TESTS();
      std::getchar(); // keep console window open until Return keystroke 
}
```

I have not changed anything in main(). it is as it was provided by `gtest`.
please tell me how I can remove these errors and make my program user interactive?

Answer (score 3):

This code is not a valid C++ because it doesn't belong to any function.

```
cout << "Enter two numbers:";
cin >> a >> b;
```

It should be moved inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have this

```
cout << "Enter two numbers:";
cin >> a >> b;
Arithmatic num;
```

out of function.

Move the code inside the `main` function. Or in another function and call it in the `main`.